# Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results

Tags: flutter, xcode, cycle, runner

## **Running a Flutter project with Xcode 15.2 fails to log:

Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner': ExtractAppIntentsMetadata
○ Target 'Runner': CodeSign /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/ios/opensource/AFNetworking.framework' to '/Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output '/Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/ios/opensource/AFNetworking.framework' to '/Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework'

Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node:  ->

command:  ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ExtractedAppShortcutsMetadata.stringsdata ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:ExtractAppIntentsMetadata ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase7-copy-files ->

node: <CodeSign /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework> ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:CodeSign /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework ->

node: <Copy /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework> ->

CYCLE POINT ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:Copy /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/ios/opensource/AFNetworking.framework ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase6--cp--copy-pods-resources ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-E817602B2947E873EE031CF0-Pods-Runner-resources-Debug-input-files-cbdaeeee3b9f6d722922600f6aafb12e-resolved.xcfilelist ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-E817602B2947E873EE031CF0-Pods-Runner-resources-Debug-input-files-cbdaeeee3b9f6d722922600f6aafb12e-resolved.xcfilelist ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase5--cp--embed-pods-frameworks ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-CF1D39E121829D17F214509C-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files-76316764b0f21125013943d815274e69-resolved.xcfilelist ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-CF1D39E121829D17F214509C-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files-76316764b0f21125013943d815274e69-resolved.xcfilelist ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase4-thin-binary ->

node:  ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution Thin Binary /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-3B06AD1E1E4923F5004D2608.sh ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: � ->

directoryContents: /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/ios/Runner/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:Copy /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/ios/opensource/AFNetworking.framework

## ****Failed logs when running a Flutter project using android studio:

Launching lib/main.dart on Zeng的iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: NJT84644HS
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           41.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/ios/opensource/AFNetworking.framework' to '/Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output '/Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/ios/opensource/AFNetworking.framework' to '/Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework'

Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node:  ->

command:  ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking ->

CYCLE POINT ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:Copy /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/ios/opensource/AFNetworking.framework ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase6--cp--copy-pods-resources ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/ATAuthSDK.bundle ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-E817602B2947E873EE031CF0.sh ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-E817602B2947E873EE031CF0-Pods-Runner-resources-Debug-input-files-cbdaeeee3b9f6d722922600f6aafb12e-resolved.xcfilelist ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-E817602B2947E873EE031CF0-Pods-Runner-resources-Debug-input-files-cbdaeeee3b9f6d722922600f6aafb12e-resolved.xcfilelist ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase5--cp--embed-pods-frameworks ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-CF1D39E121829D17F214509C.sh ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-CF1D39E121829D17F214509C-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files-76316764b0f21125013943d815274e69-resolved.xcfilelist ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-CF1D39E121829D17F214509C-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files-76316764b0f21125013943d815274e69-resolved.xcfilelist ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase4-thin-binary ->

node:  ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution Thin Binary /Users/cengchanghuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-avikankkqxmuwwhcadhnwatinodr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-3B06AD1E1E4923F5004D2608.sh ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: \ ->

directoryContents: /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/ios/Runner/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:Copy /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework /Users/cengchanghuan/Desktop/workspace/ksmart/ios/opensource/AFNetworking.framework

Error launching application on Zeng的iPhone.

I've tried changing the Build Phases order, but it still fails[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIp5K.png)

Answer (score 1):

i think you should try to move Embed Foundation Extensions below Copy Bundle Resources like in this image[image]